# Delete with multiple where clauses extremely slow

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I run a php/mysql application that help manage information for school districts. I have a "students" table that I update every night with a CRON job based on information that is sent to my server by SFTP.

The job parses the data in the csv files that are sent and inserts the data in a table called "students_temp". Then I compare the students_temp to students and delete and rows where the data matches, update students that exists but have changed info, and insert new students.

The job takes approximately 380 seconds to complete and 97% of this time is spent on the DELETE statement. Below are the two tables, and the delete statement, I have to imagine the issue lies with the multiple where clauses but I am not sure how to fix it.

**Students**

```
student_id  int(11)
student_ts  timestamp
student_local_id    varchar(100)
student_nj  bigint(11)
student_first   varchar(250)
student_last    varchar(250)
student_grade   int(11)
student_school  int(11)
student_district    int(11)
student_gender  varchar(1)
student_eth_american_indian int(1)
student_eth_asian   int(1)
student_eth_black   int(1)
student_eth_hispanic    int(1)
student_eth_pacific int(1)
student_eth_white   int(1)
student_status  int(1)
student_contact_name    text
student_address text
student_city    text
student_state   text
student_zip varchar(30)
```

**Students_Temp**

```
student_temp_id int(11)
student_temp_ts timestamp
student_temp_local_id   varchar(100)
student_temp_nj bigint(11)
student_temp_first  varchar(250)
student_temp_last   varchar(250)
student_temp_grade  int(11)
student_temp_grade_code varchar(255)
student_temp_school int(11)
student_temp_school_code    varchar(255)
student_temp_district   int(11)
student_temp_gender varchar(1)
student_temp_eth_american_indian    int(1)
student_temp_eth_asian  int(1)
student_temp_eth_black  int(1)
student_temp_eth_hispanic   int(1)
student_temp_eth_pacific    int(1)
student_temp_eth_white  int(1)
student_temp_status int(1)
student_temp_contact_name   text
student_temp_address    text
student_temp_city   text
student_temp_state  text
student_temp_zip    varchar(30)
```

**SQL DELETE STATEMENT**

```
DELETE st FROM students_temp st
    INNER JOIN students s ON student_temp_local_id=student_local_id
    WHERE student_temp_nj=student_nj 
    AND student_temp_first=student_first 
    AND student_temp_last=student_temp_last
    AND student_temp_grade=student_grade
    AND student_temp_school=student_school
    AND student_temp_district=student_district
    AND student_temp_gender=student_gender
    AND student_temp_eth_american_indian=student_eth_american_indian
    AND student_temp_eth_asian=student_eth_asian
    AND student_temp_eth_black=student_eth_black
    AND student_temp_eth_hispanic=student_eth_hispanic
    AND student_temp_eth_pacific=student_eth_pacific
    AND student_temp_eth_white=student_eth_white
    AND student_temp_status=student_status
    AND student_temp_contact_name=student_contact_name
    AND student_temp_address=student_address
    AND student_temp_city=student_city
    AND student_temp_state=student_state
    AND student_temp_zip=student_zip;
```

Comment: are they all (fields used in WHERE) indexed?

Comment: If your tables have indexes, then those indexes need to be modified with every delete statement. You might consider dropping the indexes for the delete, then rebuilding them afterwards

Comment: How many rows does the table have, and is it using InnoDB or MyISAM storage engine?

Comment: I don't think I have indexes (foreign keys?) setup. The students table has about 25k and the updates are at about 18-20k. I'm not sure where I find the answer about the storage engine.

Comment: Deleting lots of rows is slow to begin with, which is why when deleting an entire table you use truncate.

Comment: Is this an error? `AND student_temp_last=student_temp_last`

Comment: Rather than delete from your temp table, maybe you could just mark the record as a duplicate. Then drop the whole table when you're done.

Comment: @Ollie - Certainly looks like one to me, can't imagine why I would have done that intentionally. Will update this in the morning to see if it makes a difference.

Comment: make sure you have indexes on students.student_local_id and students_temp.student_temp_local_id.

Comment: I think it isn't the `where` clause which making it slow, it's rather the `inner join`

Comment: The error Ollie noted did not have an effect, the script actually ran even longer last night, not sure that it was directly related to that change though.

Answer (score 0):

first, the fields you are using to join the tables should be indexed (student_local_id and student_temp_local_id). if those fields are identifiers make unique indices. if they are not indexed, for each row in the first table you are scanning all rows from the other table. 
just adding an index will speed up your process.

second, it's not necessary to delete unmodified rows from temp_table to update the other. you can just update the rows that are modified, and insert the rows that don't exist in students

you can do something like this to update

```
update table students a join students_temp b on b.student_temp_local_id=a.student_local_id
set a.field1 = b.field1, a.field2 = b.field2, ...
where a.field1 <> b.field1 or a.field2 <> b.filed2 or...
```

and to insert the new ones

```
insert into students (field1, field2, ...)
    select field1, field2, ...
    from students_temp a
    where not exists (select 1 from students where student_local_id = a.student_temp_local_id);
```

Comment: It seems like adding the indexes on the to student_local_id fields improved the transaction time on the script as reported by New Relic from approximately 385,000ms to 5,700ms!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like adding the indexes on the to student_local_id fields improved the transaction time on the script as reported by New Relic from approximately 385,000ms to 5,700ms!!